# Compare two images one in an SQL DB and the other local

Tags: php, image, sql-server-2005

I am connecting to a clients database, in this database are a list of images stored in image format (sql2005), Whenever the client updates an image I need to update the image stored on their website (LAMP)

Is there a best approach for this?  There is no update date field on the database and I can't alter it either, my theory was to do an md5 check and compare the results but I doubt that will work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need to transfer the image from SQL database to the web server or where ever you are serving the images from.

If you don't have any flag of when the image has changed. You are going to have to check all images. Comparing hashes should be sufficient. This should be done with a script running on an interval (cron). If you have a large number of images to check, you may want to use some sort of a job queue and run workers on several machines.